# select wordpress custom post type

Tags: php

I have one wordpress theme which contain Custom Post Type.

And in my theme I can add that as a page which show some different URL.

Now when I call a WP function `(is_page('some-page'))` for wordpress page so this code is working.

Now for my Custom page I write that same code but it's not working.

So my question is how can we call this kind of specific custome page in wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check Wordpress theme hierarchy and you will know which file you need to create for custom post types :-)

http://codex.wordpress.org/File:Template_Hierarchy.png

Most likely you are after archive-$posttype.php

Comment: Thanks for your replay,
This is exactly what I want thanks a lot.

Comment: try get_post_type( $post->ID ) == "[YOUR POST TYPE]"

Comment: is_single is work in my case